# Resource id from Contact Photo URI on Android

Tags: android, uri, contacts, android-drawable, resource-id

I only know how to use a Uri for the contact photo i.e. `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/100/photo`

Is there a way to "extract" the int resource id for a contact photo from the Uri?

Comment: Why would you need the resource id when you can use openinputstream method when you query the uri (via contentresolver) and then use decodestream from bitmapfactory to decode the image.

Comment: I was trying to use kpbird's chip library, which only accepts resource id's. I could've edited the library to use your suggestion, but instead I just now implemented the code from frameworks/ex/chips as a library project, which does all the work for me.